# Smallest non-halting unlambda program

Tags: lambda-calculus, halting-problem, combinatory-logic

Is ```` ```sii``sii ```` the smallest [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/~david/programs/unlambda/#ref) program that doesn't halt?

In other words, what is the smallest non-terminating combinator term in [SKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) augmented with $C$ ([call/cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation)) and $D$ ([delay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation))? Is it $SII(SII)$?

Comment: What do you think?  What have you tried?  Have you tried enumerating all smaller unlambda programs, and trying to determine if they can halt or not?  If you tried that, where did you get stuck?   (You might try writing a little program to help with that.  While the halting problem is undecidable in general, for any specific instance, you might be able to figure it out pretty readily.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intuitively speaking, a non-terminating program needs either:

- a combinator such as $Y$ which, when applied, reduces to a larger expression containing itself;
- or two combinators such as $S$ which, when applied, replicate at least one of their arguments: one to do the initial replication and one to be replicated.

Unlambda lacks a combinator of the first type, but has two combinators of the second type: $S$ and $C$.

In the SKI-calculus, following the intuition above, a non-terminating term needs to somehow apply $S$ with the first argument being $S$. So it would have to be of the form $Swx(Syz)$, i.e. ```` ```swx``syz ```` in Unlambda). This suggests that $SII(SII)$ is minimal. (Note that I've only given an intuition, I haven't proved it!)

However Unlambda also includes `c` (call/cc), and this is a very powerful operator in terms of replicating its argument. A term of the form $Cfx$ applies its own continuation $\phi$ to the function $f$; if $f \phi$ itself arranges not to destroy its context, then the term won't terminate. For example, $CI(CI)$ is non-terminating (exercise: work it out). ``` ``ci`ci ``` is known as the [Yin-Yang puzzle](http://yinwang0.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/yin-yang-puzzle/). To see it in action, make it print a trace of its execution: ``` ``.@`ci`.*`ci ```.

Because $S$ requires 3 arguments and $C$ requires 2, intuitively, there can't be a non-terminating 3-combinator term, so the 4-combinator term we found above is minimal.

Here's a quick-and-dirty bash script that enumerates all possible Unlambda terms of up to 4 combinators (i.e. 3 application nodes) and prints out the ones that take more than 1 second to terminate. I omitted the I/O primitives which reduce like `i`, as well as `e` (exit) which obviously wouldn't help to make a program non-terminating. This is an experimental way to list the non-terminating terms — the terms not printed here are guaranteed to be terminating (assuming a correct implementation), and the terms printed here are likely to be non-terminating.

```
for a in s k i c d v; do
  for b in s k i c d v; do
    for c in s k i c d v; do
      for d in s k i c d v; do
        for p in @$a$b @@$a$b$c @$a@$b$c @@@$a$b$c$d @@$a@$b$c$d @@$a$b@$c$d @$a@@$b$c$d @$a@$b@$c$d; do
          p=${p//\@/\`}
              timeout 1 unlambda <<<$p || echo $p
        done
      done
    done
  done
done
```

The result of the experiment is that only the following terms are potentially non-terminating:

````
```scc?
``c?`c?
````

where each `?` can be independently `i`, `c` or `d`. In other words, the non-terminating combinator terms are $SCCx$ and $Cx(Cy)$ (or so the experiment suggests, but it happens to be correct).

Exercises:

- Work out the reductions for these terms and check that they are indeed non-terminating. Do they loop or do they grow forever?
- Prove that all smaller terms terminate. (I don't think there's anything more interesting than a long case enumeration.)
- How does $SCCI$ relate with my intuition above concerning the minimum content of a non-terminating term — the $S$ replicates only $I$?
- Prove or disprove that there is no smaller non-terminating SKI term than $SII(SII)$. Are there others of the same size?